# Multiple internalviewresolvers Spring+JavaConfig

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

in my application i have multiple web modules(Maven)
each modules has to configure its own view revolvers (InternalViewResolver)

When i give the config like this in both modules, its not working it takes only first one that is main module's one

**Main Module**

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

**Sub Module**

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/users");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setOrder(2);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

How to handle this?

Comment: It will never work... A `UrlBasedViewResolver` always returns a view so multiple `InternalResourceViewResolver`s don't work. Next to that you here have 2 view resolvers with the same name, one overriding the other and with exactly the same config...

Comment: how can i configure the view if i need to add different prefix for submodules

Comment: That doesn't matter, you cannot (currently) have multiple `UrlBasedViewResolvers` regardless of their configuration.